# How to get top trending topics of Twitter using Twitter API and pass it to a query parameter using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am new to Nodejs. I am trying to get the top trending topics on twitter and then use these to search and post tweets.
I am using twit npm module and want to pass the retrieved trending topics to the q parameter in object params.

```
var params= { 
    q:' ', 
    result_type:'recent',
    lang:'en'
}
```

So later I can pass this variable in

```
Twitter.get('search/tweets',params,function(err,data) {
...}
```

and retweet them.